# Application or web service to upload video files to Youtube while keeping hyphens in filenames

Tags: video, web-services, youtube

I have a couple of videos with hyphens in their names:

[image]

When I upload them on Youtube, hyphens disappear:

[image]

I'm looking for an application or web service that can:

- upload several videos at once to YouTube while keeping hyphens in filenames

And if possible:

- works on Windows 10
- free

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube is removing the dashes/hyphens/underscores **after** it's uploaded to them, so no external application can have any say to prevent that.

If you want *something* there in the filenames, maybe you can replace the hyphens in the filenames to an ***en dash*** (`–`) or the wider *em dash* (`—`) instead. They look very much like hyphens, and YouTube does keep those in place!